Accessing BigQuery Dataset from a Different GCP Project Using PySpark on Dataproc
I am working with BigQuery, Dataproc, Workflows, and Cloud Storage in Google Cloud using Python.
I have two GCP projects:

gcp-project1: contains the BigQuery dataset gcp-project1.my_dataset.my_table

gcp-project2: contains my myscript.py and my files stored in Cloud Storage


In myscript.py, I am trying to read a SQL query from a file stored in Cloud Storage (query1=gs://path/bq.sql) and query data from the BigQuery dataset in gcp-project1.
According to the documentation here, when reading from BigQuery using a SQL query, I need to set the properties viewsEnabled=true and materializationDataset=dataset.
Here are the approaches I tried:
Test 1:
spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("materializationDataset", "my_dataset")

This fails because it searches for the dataset in gcp-project2 (where myscript.py is running), but my dataset is in gcp-project1. The error is: Not found: Dataset gcp-project2:my_dataset was not found in location...
Test 2:
spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("materializationDataset", "gcp-project1.my_dataset")

This fails with the error: Dataset IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores) and must be at most 1024 characters long.
Test 3:
spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("materializationDataset", "my_dataset")

try:
    df = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
        .option('project', 'gcp-project1') \ #Adding gcp-project1 contains dataset
        .option('query', query1) \
        .load()
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(10)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Failed to read data from BigQuery: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

This also fails with the same error: Not found: Dataset gcp-project2:my_dataset was not found in location...
Question:
How can I configure my PySpark script to read data from a BigQuery dataset in gcp-project1 while running the script in gcp-project2?
Any suggestions for interacting with datasets across different GCP projects would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

I think the error is due to permission issues on your dataset.
Few steps check

Service account / User running the dataproc job should have Read permission on the Bigquery Dataset/Table
Make sure that the Dataset and Dataproc jobs are in same region


@BrahmanandSingh the error is related  service account, thank you for your help.

ok, I will post the comment as an answer for better visibility, you may accept that as an answer.

// elaborating the comment
If the table exists and while accessing the same we get error : Not found: Dataset "project.dataset" was not found in location... then it usually occur due to permission issues on the dataset.
Few steps check

Service account / User running the Dataproc job should have Read
permission on the BigQuery Dataset/Table .
Make sure that the Dataset and Dataproc Clusters are in same region


Thank you, the error is related SA and also I added Temp BigQuery dataset in materializationDataset on gcp-project2.
